# How to install subversion on local machine

Tags: apache, svn

Are there any special requirements for machine to install local subversion? For example do I need apache or something else?

Comment: https://subversion.apache.org/faq.html#need-apache

Answer (score 0):

If you want to host your repo local or on LAN-drive, you need only [`svnadmin create your_repoPath`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svnadmin.c.create.html)

If you want to to set up the local server, you can run the [Custom Subversion Server](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svnserve.html), or [VisualSVN server](https://www.visualsvn.com/server/)